# What is the type of this directed graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed graph. Suppose that $G$ has the following properties:

- the vertex set $V$ is partitioned into $T$-parts $V_0,V_1, \dots, V_{T-1}$, and
- for any edge in $E$, if its initial vertex is in $V_i$ for some $i$, then its terminal vertex is in $V_{i+1 \textrm{ mod }T}$.

**Question**
What is the type of this graph?

In an article that I found, it is called a $T$-partite graph. However, when I look into the definition of a partite graph, it only specifies that any edge cannot begin and end with vertices in the same part, unlike the condition above.

Please be noted that I am not familiar with graph theory in details. I am not sure whether this type of graphs is common in graph theory. I tried searching for terms like phase graph or cyclic graph, but this wasn't it.

To demonstrate such graph, here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxZoX.png). Actually, this is a labelled graph, and it appears when I study sofic shifts.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this condition has a name, but it can be stated in the language of [graph homomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism). Namely, this is equivalent to the graph admitting a homomorphism to the directed cycle graph $C_T$.

Various other conditions on a graph can also be stated in this form, e.g. an undirected graph is $T$-partite, or equivalently $T$-colorable, iff it admits a homomorphism to the complete graph $K_T$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a *slightly* different condition that's equivalent if we assume that the graph is strongly connected (that there is a directed path from any vertex to any other vertex). Under this assumption, such a partition exists if and only if the length of every cycle is divisible by $T$.

(The "only if" direction is easy to see. On the other hand, if the length of every cycle is divisible by $T$, and some $u-v$ path in the graph has length $k \pmod T$, then every $v-u$ path must have length $T-k \pmod T$. In particular, every $v-u$ path has the same length modulo $T$. So we can partition the vertices into $T$ classes by the length of a path from $v$ modulo $T$, and this partition does what we want.)

There's some terminology along these lines, but most applications focus on the opposite condition: a directed graph is **[aperiodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_graph)** if the GCD of all cycle lengths is $1$. In general, that GCD is called the **period** of $G$, but it's not quite true that the existence of the partition $V_0, V_1, \dots, V_{T-1}$ means the graph has period $T$: it's possible that there's a smaller partition with the same property, and so the period is actually some proper divisor of $T$. You could also say that a graph is **periodic** if it has any period $T>1$.